# Checkbox and Yes/No ASP.Net-Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a page where it populates questions. There are two types of questions.

First one Yes/No, 
Second one multiple choice with checkboxes. The multiple choices varies from 2- 5.

Depending on the question I need to generate a string which can be used in aspx.cs file

The format of string is :

`string value="1=true, 2=false,3=false,4= true"`

if 1 and 4 options are selected(checkbox options).

The string format for Yes/No would be

```
   string value= "1=false, 2= false, 3=false,4=false"
```

Could any body help me how To do this using jquery in asp.net

Thank you 
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out serialize? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/